# Problems with datepicker bootstrap - selecting date disable

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

[image]

Somebody can help me with this problem?

I only have one week to deliver

Below is the html code in angular , I don't know what I did wrong

I only have one week to deliver

```
  <input
             type="text"
                class="form-control rangeDate"
                (bsValueChange)="changeDate($event)"
                [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
                [maxDate]="maxDate"
                #drp="bsDaterangepicker"
                bsDaterangepicker
                [(bsValue)]="dateRangePickerValue"
              />
```

```
  public datePickerValue: Date = new Date();

  public dateRangePickerValue?: (Date | undefined)[];

  public range1: Date = new Date();

  public range2: Date = new Date();

  minMode: BsDatepickerViewMode = 'month';

  bsConfig?: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  maxDate: Date;

  constructor(
    private service: FinancialReportsService,
    private toasterService: ToasterService,
    private localeServices: BsLocaleService,
    private helper: ErpgrafService
  ) {
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate());
    this.localeServices.use('pt-br');
    this.bsConfig = {
      containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue',
      minMode: this.minMode,
      rangeInputFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
      showWeekNumbers: false,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to take the last month of the year that we are

Comment: Hi Lucas, this might help you to ask questions that will get answered faster :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask but I know sometimes it can be hard to write questions in another language. Maybe a friend can help you... Good luck